# Not able to run 2 jquery scripts. If pagination works then filter doesn't and vice versa

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

JQuery not working  when called together

Below code doesn't show any error but doesn't work.

I am facing following problem

1 to 10 data is display in table with page number 1 but on clicking next button it changes the page number to 2 but data of next 10 to 20 is not displayed.

I tried JQuery Noconflict but it didn't work.

If i change the format of the Javascript it stops working.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#dg').datagrid({
    view: detailview,
    detailFormatter: function(index, row) {
      return '<div style="padding:2px"><table id="ddv-' + index + '"></table></div>';
    },
    onExpandRow: function(index, row) {
      $('#ddv-' + index).datagrid({
        url: 'https://www.ntf.mlohia.in/taka_deliver_getdetail.php?chall_no=' + row.chall_no,
        fitColumns: true,
        singleSelect: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        loadMsg: '',
        height: 'auto',
        columns: [
          [{
              field: 'sr_no',
              title: 'Sr No',
              width: 200
            },
            {
              field: 'meter',
              title: 'Meter',
              width: 100,
              align: 'right'
            },
            {
              field: 'color',
              title: 'Color',
              width: 100,
              align: 'right'
            }
          ]
        ],
        onResize: function() {
          $('#dg').datagrid('fixDetailRowHeight', index);
        },
        onLoadSuccess: function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('#dg').datagrid('fixDetailRowHeight', index);
          }, 0);
        }
      });
      $('#dg').datagrid('fixDetailRowHeight', index);
    }
  });
});


$(function() {
  var dg = $('#dg').datagrid();

  dg.datagrid('enableFilter');

});
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/datagrid-detailview.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/datagrid-filter.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.ntf.mlohia.in/css/easyui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">

<body>
  <table id="dg" style="width:90%;margin-left:5%;height:420px !important;" url="http://ntf.mlohia.in/taka_deliver_getdata.php" title="Taga Delivered" toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true" rownumbers="true" singleSelect="true" fitColumns="true">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th field="chall_no" width="6%" align="center" sortable="true">Chall No</th>
        <th field="party_name" width="22%" align="center" sortable="true">Party Name</th>
        <th field="po_no" width="5%" align="center" sortable="true">Po No</th>
        <th field="date" width="7%" align="center" sortable="true">Date</th>
        <th field="dyeing" width="17%" align="center" sortable="true">Dyeing</th>
        <th field="transport" width="17%" align="center" sortable="true">Tansport</th>
        <th field="design_name" width="9%" align="center" sortable="true">Design Name</th>
        <th field="total_meter" width="6%" align="center" sortable="true">Total Meter</th>
        <th field="rate" width="4%" align="center" sortable="true">Rate</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and changed all http to https - you do not actually USE noConflict, it is not enough to declare it. Anyway - please make the snippet into a [mcve] because it does not actually do anything right now. Add the data grid plugin and enough data to show something. Also you are using an ANCIENT jQuery

Comment: how to use noconflict in this .i added edatagrid.js but getting error ...Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.datagrid is undefined.. problem is query mini and jquery 1.4.4 getting conflict as i think ..

Answer (score 0):

You need more scripts

I added `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.edatagrid.js"></script>`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#dg').datagrid({
    view: detailview,
    detailFormatter: function(index, row) {
      return '<div style="padding:2px"><table id="ddv-' + index + '"></table></div>';
    },
    onExpandRow: function(index, row) {
      $('#ddv-' + index).datagrid({
        url: 'taka_deliver_getdetail.php?chall_no=' + row.chall_no,
        fitColumns: true,
        singleSelect: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        loadMsg: '',
        height: 'auto',
        columns: [
          [{
              field: 'sr_no',
              title: 'Sr No',
              width: 200
            },
            {
              field: 'meter',
              title: 'Meter',
              width: 100,
              align: 'right'
            },
            {
              field: 'color',
              title: 'Color',
              width: 100,
              align: 'right'
            }
          ]
        ],
        onResize: function() {
          $('#dg').datagrid('fixDetailRowHeight', index);
        },
        onLoadSuccess: function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('#dg').datagrid('fixDetailRowHeight', index);
          }, 0);
        }
      });
      $('#dg').datagrid('fixDetailRowHeight', index);
    }
  });
});


$(function() {
  var dg = $('#dg').datagrid();

  dg.datagrid('enableFilter');

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.edatagrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/datagrid-detailview.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/datagrid-filter.js"></script>


<table id="dg" style="width:90%;margin-left:5%;height:420px !important;" url="taka_deliver_getdata.php" title="Taga Delivered" toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true" rownumbers="true" singleSelect="true" fitColumns="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th field="chall_no" width="6%" align="center" sortable="true">Chall No</th>
      <th field="party_name" width="22%" align="center" sortable="true">Party Name</th>
      <th field="po_no" width="5%" align="center" sortable="true">Po No</th>
      <th field="date" width="7%" align="center" sortable="true">Date</th>
      <th field="dyeing" width="17%" align="center" sortable="true">Dyeing</th>
      <th field="transport" width="17%" align="center" sortable="true">Tansport</th>
      <th field="design_name" width="9%" align="center" sortable="true">Design Name</th>
      <th field="total_meter" width="6%" align="center" sortable="true">Total Meter</th>
      <th field="rate" width="4%" align="center" sortable="true">Rate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```